# How to create multiple skins for struts 2 application

Tags: struts2, struts

As i mention in title, how to create multiple skins for struts 2 application

I mean about design web skins it mean css - header - body - footer and so on...

Example, i have a skins basic with black and white and i have another skin with blue and white, how can i replace basic skin with another skin by upload new skin?

Comment: Very unclear what you want to know. If you want to know how to put in a header, body and footer, please say so. If you want to know how to edit CSS, please say so. Struts2 is a framework, and not a web template or something. My best guess is that you're looking for jQuery UI OR that you want to know how to import files into a JSP. Can you please improve your question?

Comment: @Akku thank you for rely, i mean about skin (layout) when i have deafult skin with 1 left column and content, then i have another skin with 2 column and content center. Like Joomla, you can download skin from Joomlart or another site provides Joomla skin and then upload and choose what skin you want to show!
Thank You!

Comment: The Joomla skins are most probably useful for Joomla. The word skin is often used very differently for many applications, but in Struts2 this word isn't used. So can you try to speak in general terms? E.g. are there HTML files, CSS files and JavaScript files included? Do you use JSPs in your app? When you say "by upload new skin", do you mean you want to show dynamic CSS in your running Struts2 Application, and the user can upload this CSS file with a form?

Comment: exactly, user can upload their own css and html file to replace position or just change color about pages! i mean that !